# Sequelize upsert with conditions on previous data

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a server that accepts RESTful-style requests.  For PUT of a certain class of objects, I want to either insert a new record with the request body data, or update a previous record.  For that, I'm using Sequelize upsert.

```
app.put('/someModel/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  data.id = req.params.id;
  models.SomeModel.upsert(data).then(() => {
    return models.SomeModel.findByPk(req.params.id);
  }).then(res.send.bind(res)).catch(next);
});
```

On update, I only want to update the database record if it hasn't previously been changed.  That is, if a Client A fetches a record, Client B then modifies that record, and then Client A subsequently tries to update it, the request should fail since the record was updated by Client B in between Client A's fetch and update.  (On the HTTP side, I'm using the `If-Unmodified-Since` request header.)

Basically, I need a way to:

```
UPDATE table
SET
  field1="value1",
  field2="value2"
WHERE
  id=1234 AND
  updatedAt="2019-04-16 17:41:10";
```

That way, if the record has been updated previously, this query won't modify data.

How can I use Sequelize upsert to generate SQL like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for MySql, that wouldn't be valid - upsert results in

```
insert into table (field1) values ('value1') on duplicate key update field1 = values(value1);
```

The syntax doesn't allow for a WHERE clause.  Another DBMS, maybe?

With raw sql, you could fake it with the IF function:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES ('value1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  field1 = IF(updatedAt = "2019-04-16 17:41:10", values(field1), field1);
```

but it's kind of ugly.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think the differentiation between INSERT and UPDATE is part of my problem.  If it's an INSERT, whatever values come in are fine.  But if an UPDATE operation is performed, I want to ensure the record hasn't changed since the app last knew about it.

Comment: I might just restructure this and decouple the INSERT and UPDATE.